# Unable to run server (weblogic) from maven

Tags: java, maven, weblogic12c

I trying to run weblocig server with  maven (wls-maven-plugin). But, i recieve NullPointerException:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building web_application Maven Webapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- wls-maven-plugin:12.1.2.0:start-server (default-cli) @ web_application ---
[INFO] ++====================================================================++
[INFO] ++  wls-maven-plugin: start-server                                    ++
[INFO] ++====================================================================++
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.236 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-02-25T10:42:19+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/103M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.oracle.weblogic:wls-maven-plugin:12.1.2.0:start-server (default-cli) on project web_application: Error starting server: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Lab3.web_application</groupId>
    <artifactId>web_application</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>web_application Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>web_application</finalName>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
                    <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-jetty</id>
                        <phase>pre-site</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
                <artifactId>wls-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>12.1.2.0</version>

                <configuration>
                    <middlewareHome>c:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home</middlewareHome>
                    <adminurl>http://localhost:7001</adminurl>
                    <domainHome>c:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/base_domain</domainHome>
                    <user>weblogic</user>
                    <password>password123</password>
                    <upload>true</upload>
                    <remote>false</remote>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <source>./target/web_application.war</source>
                    <name>${project.build.finalName}</name>
                    <noexit>true</noexit>

                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>wls-start-domain</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start-server</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!--<execution>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>-->
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>localSnapshot</id>
            <name>local snapshot repository</name>
            <url>file:///c:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

running with -e flag:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java" "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.5" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.5\bin\m2.conf" -Didea.launcher.port=7533 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.5\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.3\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=14.0.3 deploy -e
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building web_application Maven Webapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ web_application ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ web_application ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ web_application ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Dropbox\NetCracker\Lab3\web_application\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ web_application ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ web_application ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ web_application ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [web_application] in [D:\Dropbox\NetCracker\Lab3\web_application\target\web_application]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [D:\Dropbox\NetCracker\Lab3\web_application\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [78 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: D:\Dropbox\NetCracker\Lab3\web_application\target\web_application.war
[INFO] WEB-INF\web.xml already added, skipping
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- wls-maven-plugin:12.1.2.0:start-server (wls-start-domain) @ web_application ---
[INFO] ++====================================================================++
[INFO] ++  wls-maven-plugin: start-server                                    ++
[INFO] ++====================================================================++
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.155 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-02-25T22:14:52+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/103M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.oracle.weblogic:wls-maven-plugin:12.1.2.0:start-server (wls-start-domain) on project web_application: Error starting server: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.oracle.weblogic:wls-maven-plugin:12.1.2.0:start-server (wls-start-domain) on project web_application: Error starting server
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Error starting server
    at weblogic.tools.maven.plugins.control.StartServerMojo.execute(StartServerMojo.java:112)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at weblogic.tools.maven.plugins.configure.RunScriptMojo.transformString(RunScriptMojo.java:186)
    at weblogic.tools.maven.plugins.control.StartServerMojo.defaultArgs(StartServerMojo.java:127)
    at weblogic.tools.maven.plugins.control.StartServerMojo.execute(StartServerMojo.java:57)
    ... 27 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I run it in Intellij IDEA > execute maven goal > wls:start-server.

P.S. Running manualy by call: c:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\startWebLogic.cmd was sucessful.

Comment: As the stacktrace suggests, you should use the -e switch and get a full error stacktrace. Perhaps then you can find out why the NPE is thrown (or post it so you can help here).

Comment: @Victor I added -e option. Can you check the result?

Comment: It seems that the Mojo (Maven POJO) that starts the server tries to run a script and fails transforming a string. Probably you are missing a setting that needs to be provided in order to start the server.

Comment: Yeah, maybe the cmd script is providing something else that you are not providing while running the Maven goal